# Within the context of metaphysics specifically... who originally asked the question "What is the nature of reality?"

Tags: metaphysics

This is tagged, and asked of, those that would describe themselves as metaphysicists, or those interested in viewing a question through the spectacles of mteaphysics.

So, noting "WITHIN the specific domain we refer to as Metaphysics", somewhere, sometime, somehow inspired, someone came up with the synthesized metaphysical question...

"What is the nature of reality?"

[image: Not me]

*For the record... not me!  But I like it, and say "Kudos, well done.  Succint and to the point, and uses "the" to be non-ambiguous".*

"We" the metaphysicists and metaphysics-interested have it on "our" tag page.  Yes... us, we, we philosophers/metaphysicists have it in our intro to the Metaphysics tag.

It is "our" question.

Link for reference [HERE](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metaphysics).

My question is... from whence did it come?

I guess a related question would be "Why is it there?", or "What criterion were used in its choosing?"  On the tag page, that is.  Specific and answerable questions.

The motivation for upvotes is ostensibly, demonstration of research.  So, this edit...

It is suggested that, within metaphysics, specifically, one originator of at least a similar line of questioning, reasoning was Parmenides

> The question "What is the nature of reality?" has been a central concern of metaphysics, a branch of philosophy that explores the fundamental nature of existence, being, and reality. In the Western philosophical tradition, one of the earliest thinkers to grapple with questions about the nature of reality was Parmenides, an ancient Greek philosopher who lived around the 5th century BCE.
>
> Parmenides is known for his philosophical poem, "On Nature," in which he explores the concept of being and the nature of reality. He posited that reality is singular, unchanging, and eternal, and he argued against the possibility of genuine change or plurality. Parmenides famously proclaimed, "What is, is; and what is not cannot be," suggesting that true reality is immutable and indivisible.
>
> While Parmenides did not explicitly phrase the question "What is the nature of reality?" in those terms, his exploration of the concept of being and his inquiry into the fundamental nature of existence laid the groundwork for subsequent metaphysical inquiries. His work represents an early attempt to grapple with questions about the nature of reality and the fundamental principles that govern the universe, making him a pivotal figure in the history of metaphysics.

But that doesn't answer the question of how it got selected and ended up on "our" metaphysics tag page.  Did we vote on it, perhaps?  Grab it as text from another site?  We didn't attribute it to Parmenides.  Should it be?

I guess some of those questions would be MEtaphysics-meta-questions...  not metaphysics questions.

Still, the originator of the actual question, is a good one.

Comment: In the so-called "Western world" the [Presocratics](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/presocratics/).

Comment: What should one use according to Parmenides to discover the true nature of reality?
According to Parmenides, the senses are entirely deceptive, and reason alone can lead us to truth. The nature of the world, then, can only be gotten at through a rational inquiry.

Comment: See [Parmenides: The Ways of Inquiry](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/parmenides/#WayInq). But there were also [The Milesians](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/presocratics/#Mil): sort of naturalists, as wella s [Empedocles' *On Nature*](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/empedocles/#Natu).

Comment: But yes, in the end the debate about the "right mix" of rational inquiry and empirical investigation is alive since then.

Comment: It would be folly and foolish to contrive a hypothesis that disagreed with observed observations.  However, some of our observations are dependent upon assumed interpretations.  (such as the "expansion of the universe" and the CMBR.  And may have competing and better interpretations leading to better more satisfying explanations.  Interpretation is a component to be aware of.  in observation.

Comment: >It is "our" question. If you don't know what we mean by "existence", what do you mean here by "is"?

Comment: See [Metaphysics](https://plato.stanford.edu/ENTRIES/metaphysics/) for an overview, starting with historical sources, and see e.g. John Heil, [What is Metaphysics? (2021)](https://www.google.it/books/edition/What_is_Metaphysics/PFQ_EAAAQBAJ) for a "standard" approach that avoids answering, stepping back form Metaphysics to meta-Metaphysics :-)

Comment: And compare with Martin Heidegger, [Introduction to Metaphysics (1953)](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Introduction_to_Metaphysics/ODyvAwAAQBAJ): **The Fundamental Question of Metaphysics** WHY ARE THERE beings at all instead of nothing? That is the question.

Comment: I have tended always, to shy from stepping into boxes (one never knows where might lay a dead cat, or worse, where they've been pissing)... because I always like the freedom to choose for myself, rather than choose to label myself a "this-ist" or "that-ist".  But participating in forums, may necessitate some such.  Like finding out I am a "Metaphysicist".  (I didn't know till recently).  And now, I am finding out I am a "Classical Metaphysicist"... because...

Comment: I am exactly "that one!!"... "metaphysics was, like chemistry or astrology, to be defined by its subject-matter: metaphysics was the “science” that studied “being as such” or “the first causes of things” or “things that do not change”.... but time have changes, and some contemporary philosophers have dumped their box of dead-cat-piss into the waters.  So... I am... by outside change, become a "Classical Metaphycisist, who frowns on the frivoulous contemporaries.  More new information to me.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This question and its previous variants has caused much confusion on different levels. When the question simply asks:

> Who originally proposed a general principle which explains all
> phenomena in nature?

then the answer has been given by Mauro in his comment: The Greek Presocratics. It is remarkable that the answers of nearly all Presocratics were different and incompatible with each other.

Comment: What has been called "the most intelligent photo ever taken" is the picture of Einstein, Bohr, Planck, Curie, etc, at the 1927 Solvay conference.  Their primary discussion and goal was to debate wave-particle-duality vs pilot-wave 2D "group-wave-sets".  Fundamental metaphysics/philosophy, unless verifiable directly by experimentation, at which point it can be classed science.  Kinda attacking the "material vs non-material" or "things, vs non-things" question.  Would you agree?

Comment: Hey.  The #1 question on "Hot Questions" is "Can you mathematically prove the existence of god?" or some such... the life of a mod must be quite challenging at times.  Some people wanting to discuss the nature of actual fundamental reality, others wanting to plot and scheme how to prove gods...  where to draw those fine lines between opinion and supportable fact based answerable question. 
I feel for you mods in your difficult positions. ... https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/103653/can-you-mathematically-prove-the-existence-of-god